# HIVE Sum Over query

Tags: partitioning, hiveql, olap, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to convert a query in Teradata to HIVE QL (HDF) and have struggled to find examples.
Teradata (my functional end goal) - want a count of records in the table, then  for each growth_type_id value and ultimately a % each group is.

```
select  trim(growth_type_id)      AS VAL, COUNT(1) AS cnt, SUM(cnt) over () as GRP_CNT,CNT/(GRP_CNT* 1.0000) AS perc 
from acdw_apex_account_strategy
 qualify perc > .01 group by val
```

Note: running HDP-2.4.3.0-227

Comment: Care to show the full original query and be specific about the part(s) you are finding hard to convert?

Comment: Dudu, that is the full original.   I'm struggling to confirm i can get a record count per distinct value in (growth_type_id) and grand total ....efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

```
select      val
           ,cnt
           ,grp_cnt
           ,cnt/(grp_cnt* 1.0000) as perc 

from       (select      trim(growth_type_id)    as val
                       ,count(*)                as cnt
                       ,sum(count(*)) over ()   as grp_cnt

            from        acdw_apex_account_strategy 

            group by    trim(growth_type_id)
            ) t

where       cnt/grp_cnt > 0.01 
;
```

---

- QUALIFY is unique to Teradata.
- Aliases used everywhere in the query is unique to Teradata.
- Grouping by columns positions is parameter dependent - [hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties)
- Grouping by aliases is not supported - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1683
- Hive doesn't use integer arithmetic (e.g. 7/4 - 1.75 and not 1 as in teradata)
- decimal notation without preceding digit(s) is not valid

---

P.s.
You are using QUALIFY before the GROUP BY and although Teradata syntax is agile and the only requirement is that the SELECT/WITH clause will be positioned first, I strongly recommend to keep the standard order of clauses:
WITH - SELECT - FROM - WHERE - GROUP BY - HAVING - ORDER BY